# How to create a modular JavaFX11 runnable jar/exe?

Tags: java, javafx, jlink, javafx-11

I have successfully followed the instructions mentioned in [openjfx-docs](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) (using maven)

I'm able to run it in my eclipse. I'm also able to create custom runtime images using jlink. The application could be run through the generated launcher.

Now, how do we create a runnable jar/exe with the stripped down JRE generated by jlink?

Comment: If you've built your run-time image, you can share them as `jmods` for the users consuming on Java9 or above that should work fine. I mean the example if JavaFX itself distributing `jmods` and `.jar` files for its consumption.

Answer (score 1):

I just recently started experimenting with the `jlink` tool of Java 11 and can provide a partial answer. The `java` command in the bin directory of a **custom runtime image** works just like `java` of the standard JRE:

> /path/to/custom/runtime/image/**bin/java** -jar myjar.jar

The custom runtime image must of course contain all the required dependencies, which I made sure by making myjar.jar a modularized JAR and by providing the switch

> --add-modules myjar.jar

when creating the custom runtime image with `jlink`. With the additional switch

> --launcher **mylaunchername**=modulename.of.my.jar/mypackage.with.MainClass

the directly executable binary

> /path/to/custom/runtime/image/**bin/mylaunchername**

is generated. On my Mac, I created an alias and moved that to the desktop. That's as close to an application as I could get so far, with the following caveats:

- The app icon is the standard green "exec"
- double clicking on this icon launches a terminal, which is undesirable in case of a JavaFX application
- And, of course, the "application" is not a single file, but the complete custom runtime image folder.

Comment: sir please upload a working example in github.

Comment: either you can give a link to a working example.